# why jenkins-workflow just build first job from a list?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am trying to use the jenkins-workflow plugin. With below scripts:

```
test()

@NonCPS
def test(){
     String[] list=['test1','test2','test3','test4']

     for (job in list){
       build job
     }
 }
```

Why just forst job "test1" is executed?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this after change the for loop.

```
for(int i=-; i< list.size(); i++){
     build list.getAt(i)
}
```

then remove the @NonCPS to fix this.

Comment: Yes you may not call an (asynchronous) step from inside `@NonCPS`. [JENKINS-31314](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31314)